# How do I interpret this delayed_job error on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying to run delayed_job on heroku and it doesn't appear to be working.  So I went into the heroku console to check out what might be going on with the following:

```
Delayed::Job.find(:last)
```

This is what I came back with:

```
=> #<Delayed::Job id: 241, priority: 0, attempts: 22, handler: "--- !ruby/struct
:SomeMailJob \ncontact: !ruby/object...", last_error: "undefined method `subject
' for #<YAML::Object:0x2ab...", run_at: "2010-09-20 05:26:52", locked_at: nil, f
ailed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, created_at: "2010-09-10 03:31:05", updated_at: "2
010-09-17 23:25:26">
```

I'm not sure what to do with this...I don't know what this YAML object is or why it is undefined....how can I start to drill down better?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `perform` method in `SomeMailJob`. That will give you more clues. You might also want to print the `last_error` to get the full stack trace. `puts Delayed::Job.find(:last).last_error` will do it for you.

You can also load the handler object:

```
handler = YAML.load(Delayed::Job.find(:last)).handler
```

Once you have the object, you can use it any way you want.

Comment: is there a way for me to inspect the object?

Comment: `Object#inspect` will yield what you have already printed. You can however override the `to_s` method and make it more readable.